# No logging to console after executing a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to start MonoDB from a NodeJS application. I can see MongoDB is started but I never get an output in my console after it is started.

This is my code:

```
// Start MongoDB.
(async () => await exec('mongod', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log('CONNECTED');
}))()
```

Comment: What is `exec`? Is it the native `child_process.exec` method or a `util.promisify()`ed version (or similar)? If it is a promisifed version the callback would not be used. You would need to use a `then()` callback from from one of the promises. From the async function call, `exec()` call or a statement after your await call. eg, `(async ()=>{...})().then(callback)` or  `await exec(...); console.log();`

Comment: It's the native child_process.exec.

Comment: Do you get the console log if you close/exit the spawned mongod window/process while keeping the original command/terminal window open. `exec` may be waiting for the process to finish in order to call the callback. You might want [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for daemon processes due to this as you can add `data` `close` etc listeners

Comment: Before I start experimenting with that could you tell me what stdout end stderr are? I am assuming that stdout is the standard output device (what would be written to the terminal).

Comment: Don't use the console, raise an exception. There you'll know the code is being run.

Comment: stdout will contain whatever the executed command would have outputted to the standard output device(terminal usually). Same for stderr but for outputted error data and device

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have found. I hope this might work.

```
(async () => {
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('mongod');
    if (stderro) {
       console.error(`error: ${stderr}`);
    }
    console.log(`Number of files ${stdout}`);
})()
```